# Converting Linq Expression to C# EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have been at this two days now. I am not very good at Linq expressions so please forgive the simplicity. I have two related tables and writing a join in TSQL would be easy but I am using Entity Framework and Linq.

I hacked out a query in LINQPad (via reading articles and tutorials) and it is returning the results as I want finally.

Now I need help turning that into C# code. I have google for translator site and find plenty of SQL to Linq but none for what I am doing....quite possibly because I don't even know that I am using the correct search terms.

My LINQPad code is this:

```
DashboardNavigations
.OrderBy(x => x.Id)
.Select(x => new 
{
    x.Id,
    x.Name,
    x.Description,
    x.ImageUrl,
    SubDash = SubDashNavs 
        .Where(s => s.DashId == x.Id)
        .Select(y => new { y.Id, y.Name, y.Description })

})
```

I am used to writing SIMPLE Linq expressions to entity framework like this:

```
var query = _mlsDashboardNavRepository.Table;
query = query.OrderBy(c => c.Id);
var dashnav = query.ToList();
```

As you can see I have the main records returning but cant get the join right.

What i am needing help with is translating the code from LINQPad to C# / EF / LINQ to SQL....????

Comment: Include how you would write it in SQL and I will show you the Linq for it.

Comment: I think the issue is that you need som context where you can access both DashboardNavigations and SubDashNavs. Correct me if I'm wrong but `_mlsDashboardNavRepository.Table` seems to be a context that only refers to DashboardNavigations.

Comment: With LINQ to SQL and the correct context (the database not a table) you should be able to write your query exactly like you did in LINQPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments I suggest that your _mlsDashboardNavRepository only refers to `DashboardNavigations` since you say you retrieve your main records using only `_mlsDashboardNavRepository.Tables`; Where is your DashboardNavigations reference? To perform your query you need a context that refers to (all) your database tables. Below is code in LINQ format using *a* database context, that might be easier on you if you're used to SQL syntax.

```
var query = (from d in context.DashboardNavigations
             join s in context.SubDashNavs on d.Id equals s.Id
             orderby d.Id ascending
             select new 
             { 
                d.Id, 
                d.Name, 
                d.Description,
                d.ImageUrl,
                SubDash = s 
             });

var dashNavs = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was making it harder than it was. It was pretty much straight up what I wrote in LINQPad.

Answer (score 0):

So I am posting this here for anyone else. It wasn't a part of my OP and NLindbom had the answer to the OP so he gets the credit. However after getting my query straightened out I wanted to project it.

My model classes were basically this:

```
public class DashboardNavigation()
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  .....etc.....
  public List<SubNav> SubDashNav {get; set;}
}

public class SubNav()
{
  ....properties....
}
```

and this LINQ project the records properly into the object.

```
         var query = _mlsDashboardNavRepository.Table
        .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Description = x.Description,
            ImageUrl = x.ImageUrl,
            SubDashNav = _mlsSubDashNav.Table
                .Where(s => s.DashId == x.Id)

        }).ToList().Select(q => new MLS_DashboardNavigation()
                            {
                                Id = q.Id,
                                Name = q.Name,
                                Description = q.Description,
                                ImageUrl = q.ImageUrl,
                                SubDashNav = q.SubDashNav.ToList()
                            }).ToList();

        return query;
```